# Getting a reverse lookup answer from nslookup but not from dig

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nslookup, dig, dns-lookup

So if I use dig to do a reverse lookup I get:

```
$ dig 71.74.56.122

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> 71.74.56.122
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41277
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;71.74.56.122.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
71.74.56.122.       655360  IN  A   71.74.56.122
```

Using nslookup, I get:

```
$ nslookup 71.74.56.122
Server:     10.0.1.1
Address:    10.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
122.56.74.71.in-addr.arpa   name = hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com.
```

Can anyone tell me why dig refuses to do the reverse lookup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dig wants the '-x' flag for reverse lookups on an IP.

Alternately, you can use the full form, 'dig PTR 122.56.74.71.in-addr.arpa.'